# Could we use these raise and rise interchangeably in some contexts?

Tags: vocabulary

Could we use rise and raise with the similar meaning, considering the following patterns? 
 Dictionary says" both of them could mean increase in amount and number"

From Oxford Dictionary: Gas rose in price

My own example: Gas has been raised

Comment: Both the sentences are weird.

Comment: I would say 'Gas prices rose' and 'The price of gas has been raised'.

Answer (score 2):

The verb 'to raise' implies an agent which does the raising.  It is a transitive verb.

> The man *(agent)* raised the flag *(object)*.

The verb 'to rise' doesn't require an agent.  It is an intransitive verb.

> The flag rose. *(rose=past tense of rise)*

Answer (score 1):

For *rise*, you could say:

> Gas **rose** in price last week.
>   Gas **has risen** in price recently.

Then for *raise*:

> Higher transportation costs forced the oil company to **raise** prices.

But things generally don't raise themselves, some outside action is needed. Rise is more about describing the effect.