# 'Raise' or 'Rise' as NOUNS and not verbs

Tags: word-choice, nouns

This question ***rose*** from [this question!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35050/could-we-use-these-raise-and-rise-interchangeably-in-some-contexts)

I'm quite clear on using *raise* and *rise* **as verbs**. However, when it comes to using them as nouns, I am bit confused. Say, I'm talking about the increment in my salary. Would it be 'raise' or 'rise'?

> *How much 'raise/rise' you are likely to get in this year's increment? ~ Not much, I guess 10%.*

Comment: Similar question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140775/raise-and-rise-revisited-but-what-if-its-a-noun)

Comment: Ah, thank you for that. That's the question. But I'll keep this here. It's helpful.

Comment: (AmE) I have never heard *rise* in this context. I would use *increase* instead.

Comment: "Not much, I guess 10%"  Please send me this company's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference between rise and raise when it means an increase in our pay or salary. As a matter of fact, we the people of the Sub-continent are sandwiched between American and British English. Anyway, if the poster follows British English, he will use the noun "rise" for the said purpose. On the contrary, if he follows American English, he will use "raise".

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking salary increments, then 'raise' is the correct term for it.

> How large a raise are you likely to get this year?

Comment: But then, *The rise I got this year was unsatisfying* is also correct.

Comment: Not in this specific context, no. Or, at least, not in my part of the world. Down here, people would take that as 'getting a rise': http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+a+rise+out+of

Comment: "The rise I got out of Maulik V this year was unsatisfying."

Comment: I guess that's not the correct use of the idiom.

Comment: It would be if I had succeeded in annoying you during 2014, but your reaction to the annoyance wasn't particularly entertaining.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the difference between verbs:

> Raise of *something else*
>
> Rise *[of self]*

*I received a raise of my salary* - my boss raised my salary.

*My salary rise in this year was 5%* - my salary rose by 5%.